# How to solve this following problem related to dynamical sorting and selecting of jTable?

Tags: java, swing

I am using a dynamical sorting code for jTable. The problem is that, as soon as I type, the table displays correct response and after a second, it returns to the previous original state. How to rectify this problem?

```
private void jTextField2KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable1.getModel());
        jTable1.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
        jTextField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = jTextField2.getText();

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = jTextField2.getText();

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: There is an example of how to do this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a listener to Text Field should be done in the constructor. Doing the same in a method is wrong and will not give any output that we are expecting.